# Avoid redundant mappings for C++ program

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing

This is my C++ code which is meant to do the following:

1. Compare a set of XML files and see what is different between them
2. Dump out the node if it is new (in B.xml but not A.xml)
3. Scan that node and associate tags to types of information using map
4. Do work on the data depending on what type it is

I'm pretty happy with how steps 1-2 work but 3-4 I feel I may have implemented poorly. My main concern is I have to map the tag even if if already matches, such as the id, when really it would be good to define a map only if it's different such as description.

My code:

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
 {
    // This map relates the type of content to the tag name in the XML file
    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagMap {
         {"id", "id"}, {"description", "content"}, {"url", "web_address"}, {"location", "location"}
     };

    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
     std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("entry")) {
     const char* id = node.child_value("id");
     mapa[id] = node;
     }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("data").children("entry")) {
     const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
         if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
         mapb[idcs] = node;
         }
     }

    // For added nodes
     for (auto& eb: mapb) {
         // Loop through Tag map to see if we can find tags named "id, content, web_address or location" in the node returned
         for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
         // For each result, assign the value of that tag to the type of content
         // For example: description = Testing!
         kv.first = eb.second.child_value(kv.second.c_str());
         // If it's an ID...
             if (kv.first == "id") {
             // Do work on ID value (i.e check if it's unique)
             }
             if (kv.first == "description") {
            // Do work on Description data (I.e Trim it)
             }
             if (kv.first == "url") {
             // Do work on URL data (I.e validate it)
             }
             if (kv.first == "location") {
             // Do work on location data
             }
         }
     }

}
```

Example input file:

```xml
<data>
    <entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <content>Description</content>
        <web_address>www.google.com</web_address>
        <location>England</location>
        <unrelated>Test</unrelated>
        <not_needed>Test</not_needed>
    </entry>
..
</data>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Barry I've just been told to move it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two different improvement for your points 3 and 4:

1. Simple improvement:

As key of your `tagMap` use a enum e.g.

```
enum Tags { Tag_ID, Tag_Description, ... }
```

This avoids a string comparison.

2. A more dynamic way is using polymorphism.

Define an abstract Baseclass `Tag`

```
class Tag {
public:
    virtual const char* getTagname() const = 0;
    virtual void processNode(const std::string& value) = 0;
};
```

Then implement a subclass for each tag you have.

```
class IdTag : public Tag {
public:
    const char* getTagname() const { return "Id"; }
    void processNode(const std::string& value) { /* Do something */ }
};
```

Now you can use a list of tags. `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Tag>> tagMap { new IdTag(), new DescriptionTag(), ... };`

Your new loop:

```
// For added nodes
 for (auto& eb: mapb) {
     // Loop through Tag map to see if we can find tags named "id, content, web_address or location" in the node returned
     for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
         kv->processNode(eb.second.child_value(kv->getTagname());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I don't understand about your example is, how do I relate the enum to the content. For example it's fair enough to define that "content" is a tag but how do I say the content tag is a description?

Comment: You can use the same loop as in your code. An enum just replaces the strings.